# What does "sechschillinger" mean? (probably 16th century)

Tags: meaning

I have 16th century literature that I am studying.
It contains the word *sechschillinger*.

I cannot find this word in the dictionary. 
What does it mean?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? I don't know the word, but just from looking at it, I would guess it is about something that costs 6 [Shillings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilling).

Comment: What is the text/section/paragraph about that contains this word?

Comment: _@germanresearcher_ [edit] your question as requested please.

Answer (score 5):

As user [infinitezero](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/30455/infinitezero) already commented, this word is probably derived from 
"*sechs Schilling*" - it is a coin.

I've found [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/433068?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) from 1916 by H. O. Schwabe about "Germanic Coin-Names".
On page 593 is an entry about the [Styrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Styria) (Styr.) usage:

> Styr. *sechs-schillinger* schlechte Münze.

("bad coin")

It seems this was not only one of many types of coin, but also had a (bad) quality connotation, probably due to it's low value.

The "*Historisches Lexikon Kaisersteinbruch - Der Geist des Barock*" ([here](http://www.ribera-philosophie.at/lexikon-kaisersteinbruch-bd1.pdf)) also mentions a *Sechsschillinger* (on page 153):

> Der C. K. wird aber ein *Sechsschillinger* sein u. bleiben, weil er gleich zu dem Meister lief u. alles *versechsschillingt*.

("The C.K. is and will be a "Sechsschillinger*, because he immediately ran to the master and *versechsschillingt* everything.")

This section is about judiciary in [Kaisersteinbruch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaisersteinbruch). The sentence above is about a trial in 1633. From the context one can conclude that the person C.K. was said to be what we call a snitch today.
A person who gives away information too easily, for a bad coin/ little money for example.

Hence, depending on your text, a *sechsschillinger* can be a coin or a slander.

Answer (score 5):

The Grimmsche Deutsche Wörterbuch explains [Sechsschillinger](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=DWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS23072) as

> 1) könnte eine sechs schillinge geltende münze bezeichnen.
>
> 2) quadruplator, ein verräther, auffstecher

saying it's wether a coin worth Sechs Schillinge or a traitor/informer.

---

Another [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=XMZXAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) explains it as a word from Zurich for "Zehen Kreuzerer" (coins) (presumably: Zehn Kreuzer).

---

This [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=XMZXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=sechsschillinger&source=bl&ots=kRE7BwwiiR&sig=ACfU3U1Fs8GDkv95q19QXW6S-youbnV_mw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuje_vqv7lAhXDJFAKHXMNDf8Q6AEwCHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=sechsschillinger&f=false) imply it's a word for a cheap horse

> Sie fehrt in einem rohrverdecktem Kammerwagen / denselben ziehen zween Sechsschillinger oder Schindpferde

---

And last but not least:

[Maybe it's just a surname](https://books.google.de/books?id=_SFEAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA24-PA21&lpg=RA24-PA21&dq=sechsschillinger&source=bl&ots=ZygFdiq9Ph&sig=ACfU3U2HDtnuayUJuuteAFOEgQoSeI0oAQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi23NXorv7lAhWPI1AKHQg0AfkQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=sechsschillinger&f=false)

> Mathias Sechsschillinger